# How to set the Output and Intermediate Directory in Visual Studio C++ projects generated by CMake, using Visual Studio Macros?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, vcxproj

Here is the final desired result in Visual Studio 2019 for any C/C++ project:

[image]

The key part that I am looking for are the top 2 lines in this MSVC project properties dialog:

- "Output Directory": `$(Configuration)-$(PlatformArchitecture)\`
- "Intermediate Directory": `$(Configuration)-$(PlatformArchitecture)\$(ProjectName)\`

As you can see, both use Visual Studio `$(xyz)` macros to define the target paths.

The question(s) that I've been struggling with:

1. How can I make CMake spit out these strings instead of already expanded paths into the generated vcxproj files?
2. If I want this to happen to *multiple* (or *all*) generated MSVC C/C++ project files (libraries, executables, etc.), where do I set this up *then*? Do I need to patch template files or can this be done via commandline or configuration file settings, which then *override* the `CMakeLists.txt` internally defined values?
3. Anything special I need to mind / watch out for, if I want this setting for *all* vcxproj build targets as shown in the screenshot?

   (in my case that's generally Debug+Release for both x86 and x64, so 2 Configurations and 2 Platforms in *Visual Studio speak*)

The other questions on SO (at least the ones I dug up) do not address this at all AFAICT as they replace one 'hardcoded' path with another using CMake (just using different CMake variables, but all expand to absolute paths before the vcxproj is produced).

Comment: If you don't generate Visual Studio solutions with CMake and instead open the CMake project directly in VS 2019 you can configure these paths in a `CMakeSettings.json` file as documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=msvc-160. Any reason you need to have vcxproj files at all?

Comment: The rest of the projects in the chain are all still vcxproj-based; CMake is used only for some libraries here.

Comment: @Corristo: Thanks for that link; hadn't checked the Microsoft site for this. This might do the trick.

Comment: I don't think it'll have any effect on CMake generating Visual Studio solutions (unless of course these paths are set when opening the solution for the first time, then they might). To change the output directory it might be sufficient to use `-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=$(Configuration)-$(PlatformArchitecture)`, `-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=$(Configuration)-$(PlatformArchitecture)` and `-DCMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=$(Configuration)-$(PlatformArchitecture)` when invoking CMake to build the solution. But I don't know what the Intermediate Directory would map to in CMake.

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing (CMake 3.20 and below), it is not possible to set the intermediate directory in Visual Studio. This was requested a long time ago, but no progress has been made. See: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/14999

Note that a single CMake build can only target **one** architecture, so the resulting Visual Studio solution will only ever let you pick the *configuration*, not the *platform*. Writing `$(PlatformArchitecture)` *would work* (returning `64` or `32` appropriately), but it would be pointlessly non-portable. Also, CMake gives you portable access to `$(Configuration)` in multi-config generators via the [`CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR.html) variable.

So the best thing to do is to set `CMAKE_*_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` in your top-level CMakeLists.txt.

```
get_property(is_multi_config GLOBAL PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG)
if (is_multi_config)
  # Compute the bitness of the target, same as VS's $(PlatformArchitecture)
  math(EXPR PlatformArchitecture "8 * ${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}")

  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY 
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}-${PlatformArchitecture}")
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY 
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}-${PlatformArchitecture}")
  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY 
      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}-${PlatformArchitecture}")
endif ()
```

This checks if the generator is multi-config (like Visual Studio, Xcode, or Ninja Multi-Config) and, if so, adjusts the output paths. This will give you the option later of switching away from Visual Studio to Ninja Multi-Config if you want faster builds.

Finally, you might want to use `if (WIN32 AND is_multi_config)` instead, if you only want to adjust the output paths on Windows (and not macOS or Linux).